# function.php in divi parent and divi child theme

Tags: themes, divi

[image]

Does anyone know if an update for the Divi parent theme will also update Divi child theme function.php? My page is down with a fatal error and my last guess (not that that is set in stone - I am a newbie) is that maybe something went wrong when I updated to the latest version of Divi since everything works if I activate my Divi theme, but when I activate my child theme my page comes up with this fatal error :-/ page url dindigitalehjaelper.dk/det-offentlige/

Comment: Often errors are basically text, please share them as text, not images.

Answer (score 2):

Child Themes will never have an effect on their functions.php **as long as they themselves don't get an update**. You are safe to update Divi.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Child Theme. Then you can update the Parent Theme without any worries. Because we create Child theme to store additional codes in it. So changes remains the same in Child Theme.

Also, in **Divi > Theme Options > Updated > Rollback To Previous Version** can help you in revert the changes and go back to the previous version if the updated version cause some issue/error.

Answer (score 0):

Child themes specifically exist to allow developers to apply custom styling and functions that are independent of the main theme, therefore updating the main theme has no impact on the child theme.

If you're paranoid/overly cautious, you can keep an offline backup of your function.php file and any custom CSS, so if they are unexpectedly overwritten or deleted you can quickly replace them.

Although the problem happens when you activate your child theme I'd recommend deactivating all plugins first, then trying your child theme as it may be a plugin conflict (which is often the case with WP errors).